# Angular - Wait for refresh session before call API

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito

I have an angular app using AWS Amplify for user management. In my main app component, i use auth.currentAuthentificatedUser to get user data to call APIs with the right token. But my API calls are done to fast, before the auth.currentAuthentificatedUser. How can I handle this?

Main app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AwsService} from './aws.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  public async 
  title = 'app';
  username = '';
  constructor( public awsService: AwsService) {
    this.awsService.refreshsession(() => {
      this.username=this.awsService.userData.username
      });
  }  
  ngOnInit() {


  }
};
```

homepage component calling APIs

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})




export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private _data: cotationBase, public router: Router, public awsService: AwsService, public callAPI: callAPI, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {


  }


  ngOnInit() {

          this.callAPI.getAPI('https://api-dev.cloudyproject.pauset.fr/v0/providers',(response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.awsImage = '../..'+response.aws.icon;
            this.azureImage = '../..'+response.azure.icon;

            },
            (response) => {
              console.log(response);},
            ) 

  }
```

Comment: I can't completely understand your question, although I am trying to so I can help out :)

Is `HomeComponent` used in the template for your `AppComponent`? Because you didn't provide your templates, I am not able to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Yes! sorry it wasn't really clear

Comment: So it looks like this `<app-component><home-component></home-component></app-component>`. Correct?

And the issue is that the call in the `ngOnInit` of the `HomeComponent` is firing too soon? Before the call in `AppComponent` finishes?

Comment: Yes exactly! its fired before the refresh session function of my AppComponent is finished, so it hasn't the right token yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template for your `AppComponent` go ahead and use the `*ngIf` directive. Like this:

```
<app-component>
    <home-component *ngIf="username">
    </home-component>
</app-component>
```

That way, it won't turn on the `HomeComponent` until you have the `this.username` set on the `AppComponent`. Does that make sense?

If this answer works, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: It's working in a way. But with this solution, if the user is not authentificated, he cannot access to the app.

Comment: In your response, you could set a property called `this.hasSessionResponse = true;` And then in the `ngIf` you could reference that. This way, your app will get a response (authed or not authed) before it turns on the `HomeComponent`.